# Handling multiple filenames from FileOpenDialog()

Tags: string, split, dialog, autoit

I am writing a picture editing program and am using the below snippet to choose the files:

```
$var = FileOpenDialog("",@DesktopDir,"Images (*.jpg;*.bmp;*.png)",1+4)
$var = StringReplace($var, "|", @CRLF)
```

When I select multiple files all the file names are stored in `$var` separated by the `|` symbol. I replace that symbol with a newline character. But I need to run the program for all the filenames and I can't figure out how to separate the various filenames from the variable. So my programs stops if I select multiple files.

Answer (score 5):

```
$var = FileOpenDialog("", @DesktopDir, "Images (*.jpg;*.bmp;*.png)", 1+4)
$files = StringSplit($var, "|", 2)

For $i = 0 To UBound($files)-1
    $file = $files[$i]
    ConsoleWrite($file & @CRLF) ; Do something with file
Next
```

For me the results look like this:

```
C:\Users\Manadar\Desktop
skin1.png
skin2.png
```

So it's:

- Directory of files
- File1
- File2
- File3

etc.